# How to focus on a next/previous widget

Tags: qt

I am overriding the QPlainTextEdit to become a single line edit widget. In other words I want it to look like a QLineEdit but to have the extended functionality of QPlainTextEdit, such as text formatting etc.

My only trouble so far is that I do not know how to pass focus to the next/previous widget when I press Tab/Shift+Tab when the widget derived from QPlainTextEdit is in focus. I have started with overriding keyPressEvent to capture Tab key being pressed, but then what? How to change the focus from the widget?

I can only think of too complicated solutions (such as signalling to the parent that the focus should change, but this seems as stupid overkill). I bet there must be a very simple solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `tabChangesFocus` property of your `QPlainTextEdit` object to `true` by using the [`QPlainTextEdit::setTabChangesFocus`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#tabChangesFocus-prop) function.

Comment: Thank you. This is incredibly simple and it works. I have not noticed there is such a property in QPlainTextEdit.

Answer (score 3):

I accepted the answer by thuga which is the simplest way. However I found also another one which might be more generic for widgets that do not have tabChangesFocus property. Override keyPressEvent like this:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab:
        self.parent().focusNextChild()
    elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Backtab:
        self.parent().focusPrevChild()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can try:

- Create `QAction` and add it to the widget. Set `QShortcut` to the action with `QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Tab)`. Connect the action whith slot which changes the focus.

or

- Use directly `new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Tab), widgetPtr, SLOT(changeFocus()));`

So there is no need now to inherit your control only to capture keyPressEvent. Note that you may need to change the shortcut context for best match to your requirements.